# SweetAlert of javascript closed automatically without click in popup window

Tags: javascript, html

I have SweetAlert created by javascript..

when click button 
`<input type="submit" value="send" name="sends" class="btn btn-lg">`
the popup window open, but it closes automatically by itself and change the page very fast...

I tried this code for stop close sweetalert itself, and refresh the page when the user click "OK" of sweetalert window.

```html
<form  method="post" action="contact.php" name="myform" onsubmit="return myFunction()">

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="full" placeholder="* Full Name" required="" >

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="last" placeholder="* Last Name" required="">

<input type="submit" value="send" name="sends" class="btn btn-lg">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
  var full=document.myform.full.value;
  var last=document.myform.last.value;
  if (full==null || last==null){
    swal("Error...!!!!!!");
    return false;
}else{
    swal("Congrats!", ", Your account is created!", "success");
    return true;}
}
</script>
```

but did not work.... any suggestions for this problem.

Comment: First, the `required` attribute will prevent you from submitting the form so your first test will never be reached.

Comment: thank you for your remarking.... I remove it .. and I'm still trying to solve the problem but I failed